# How does angular 2 saves the data?

Tags: angular, web-frontend

I'm not sure how to ask this question, but I want to know how angular2 saves the data just before submitting it to the backend part.

(for example, after filling up a form, where the data gets stored before pressing the save button?)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: What exactly do you mean *where*?

Comment: for example, when we upload a file or fill a form, does the data gets saved in a local storage or where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In a variable ?

It doesn't store anywhere else than in a variable unless you decided to.